# How to update the countdown timer once the user select a different time intervals

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

The Settings menu

[image]

The Countdown timer

Hi Guys is there any ways i can update the countdown timer when the user select a different time interval ?

Comment: or do i have to declare a runnable and handler

Comment: Better to stop current, start a new one.

Comment: you mean i have to create a new countdown timer ?

Comment: Yes, it will simple then set a new interval with current timer...

Answer (score 1):

In that case you need to cancel the current timer for that used **timer.cancel()**.
and create a new CountDownTimer with the new values.
Either that, or create your new countdown timer.

Comment: I tried but did not work example if i set 45 seconds but during the countdown i change to 30seconds it does not reflect and after the countdown it still shows 45 seconds

Comment: Since you didn't post any code... did you really cancel old timer ?

Answer (score 0):

Please stop current timer

```
if(yourTimer != null)
{
  yourTimer.cancel();
  yourTimer = null;
}
```

and, start a new one with same object name

```
yourTimer=new CountDownTimer(long newMillisInFuture, long newCountDownInterval);
//some stuff
yourTimer.start();
```

It's more simple then set a new interval to current timer. If you need more control option, you may need to create your own CountDownTimer object...

Comment: if i would keep updating means that i have to keep starting multiple timer which is not efficient. Is there any other ways to update beside keep starting the timer